# Spring MVC WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

My `web.xml` content is:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> <!-- Why not put / instead of *.html? -->
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- ContextLoader -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/conf/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/conf/applicationContext-data.xml
            /WEB-INF/conf/applicationContext-service.xml

        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

My `applicationContext.xml` is:

```
<!-- Default ViewResolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.lftechnology.controller" />

<!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" 
    /> -->

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean class="com.lftechnology.controller.EmployeeController">
    <property name="employeeService" ref="employeeService" />
    <property name="departmentService" ref="departmentService"></property>
</bean>
```

Finally the controller is:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    EmployeeService employeeService;
    DepartmentService departmentService;

    //getters setters    

    @RequestMapping("/deleteEmployee.htm")
    public String deleteEmployee(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        //
        return "redirect:viewEmployee";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/viewEmployee.htm")
    public ModelAndView viewEmployee(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //
        return new ModelAndView("viewEmployee", "model", model);
    }

}
```

**Exception:**

```
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springEmployeeAnotations/viewEmployee.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code. Everything seems right to me at least. The exception is caused when trying to get into `viewEmployee` method of the controller.Any help?

Comment: you war name is springEmployeeAnotations ?

Comment: and your url is like localhost:8080/springEmployeeAnotations/viewEmployee  ?

Comment: the url is `http://localhost:8080/springEmployeeAnotations/viewEmployee.htm`

Comment: what happens when you try http://localhost:8080/viewEmployee.htm

Comment: looks like your application is deployed as ROOT

Comment: @SubinS `localhost:8080/viewEmployee.htm` results `404`

Comment: never faced this in my spring mvc usage. springEmployeeAnotations is your context path so you dont have to specify that in controller mapping url, let s see if someone have answer for your dilemma. Also are you mapping *.htm in web.xml or *.*

Comment: i am mapping `.htm` in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*.htm </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you map your your controller class to the incoming request?

Do that using @RequestMapping("/springEmployeeAnotations")

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/springEmployeeAnotations")
public class EmployeeController { .....
```

Tp